# postgres libpq: synchronous COPY mysteriously cancelled "due to user request"

Tags: postgresql, libpq

My application is using libpq to write data to Postgres using the COPY API.  After over 900000 successful COPY+commit (each containing a single row, don't ask) actions, one errored out with the following:

```
ERROR: canceling statement due to user request
CONTEXT: COPY [...]
```

My code never calls PQcancel or related friends, which I think is precluded anyway by the fact that libpq is being used synchronously and my app is not multi-threaded.

- libpq v8.3.0
- Postgres v9.2.4

Is there any reasonable explanation for what might have caused the COPY to be cancelled?  Will upgrading libpq (as I have done in more recent versions of my application) be expected to improve the situation?

The customer reports that the Postgres server **may** have been shut down when this error was reported, but I'm not convinced since the error text is pretty specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error will be emitted when you:

- send a `PQcancel`
- use `pg_cancel_backend`
- Hit control-C in `psql` (which invokes `PQcancel`)
- Send `SIGINT` to a backend, e.g. `kill -INT` or `kill -2`.

My initial answer was incorrect, claiming that the following also produced the same error. They don't; these:

- `pg_terminate_backend`
- `pg_ctl shutdown -m fast`

will emit a different error `FATAL: terminating connection due to administrator command`.

Comment: "select pg_terminate_backend(xxxx)" and "bin/pg_ctl stop -m fast -D data" both result in "FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command"

Comment: "select pg_cancel_backend(xxxx)" gets the error I'm looking for